# How to handle Key press ctrl+shift+A in sdi mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am new to vc++.How to handle Key press ctrl+shift+A in sdi mfc.
For ctrl + A code is working fine.

```
case _T('A'): 

     if(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000){
         MessageBox(_T("Key Ctrl+A is pressed"));
     }
     else if((GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)&&(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)){
         MessageBox(_T("Key Ctrl+Shift+A is pressed"));
     }

    break;
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first `if`-clause is true, whether the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed or not, so you'll never reach the `else`-clause. If you change the order of your statements, you'll get both:

```
case _T( 'A' ): 
    if ( ( GetKeyState( VK_CONTROL ) < 0 ) && ( GetKeyState( VK_SHIFT ) < 0 ) {
        MessageBox( _T( "Key Ctrl+Shift+A is pressed" ) );
    } else if ( GetKeyState( VK_CONTROL ) < 0 ) {
        MessageBox( _T( "Key Ctrl+A is pressed" ) );
    }
    break;
```

If you want to handle key presses globally, you could use [Keyboard Accelerators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645526.aspx) instead. The most straightforward way to set up accelerators is through an [ACCELERATORS resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380610.aspx).